# Одна база данных или несколько?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Прошу рассудить спор, привести аргументы, ввиду того, что мое мнение как специалиста для заказчика, видимо, ничего не значит или я не специалист вовсе.

Клиент хочет для данных пользователя отельный сервер БД, для истории платежей пользователей отдельную бд, для новостей на сайте отдельную бд и т.д.
В аргументацию приводится: "Переключение бд писать просто", "Так надежней от взломов", "Отказоустойчивость", "Не будет зависаний".

Мои аргументы: х2 удорожание бюджета на разработку, тестирование и поддержание. Бессмысленность всей затеи, так как существуют таблицы (вау), кеширование, параллельный доступ к разным данным, транзакции и блокировки в случае доступа к одним и тем же данным. Причем, блокировки нужны только при изменении данных, а при чтении без проблем параллельные запросы чтения проходят. Беспроблемное выполнение множества запросов в одном соединении. А в случае с несколькими бд, нужно постоянно переключать соединения, что отражается на производительности.

Вот скажите мне, зачем старые данные и новые данные находящиеся на модерации надо разносить на две базы на разных серверах? Как между двумя удаленными базами строить JOIN запросы, когда это элементарно делается когда данные в разных таблицах?

Может я что то не понимаю. Прошу подтвердить или опровергнуть мои доводы.

Comment: Для хотелок клиента нужны не разные бд, а разные микросервисы.

Comment: Сочувствую
А насчет старых и новых данных - это хороший приём. Партиционаированием называется. Только зачем на 2 физическиеских сервера разносить тоже не понимаю. 
Твой собеседник где-то что-то слышал или хочет тебе показать, что не далек от программистских штучек) я бы успокоился и ещё раз все аргументировал бы как профессионал. Потому что в его интересах сделать тоже как можно лучший продукт, а в споре рождается истина :)

Comment: @PythonicSpeaker Конкретно ситуация с редактированием профиля пользователя. Пользователь редактирует свои данные, сохраняет. Эти данные потом проверяет модератор, одобряет или отклоняет изменения. Так почему таблица user_data и user_data_temp хуже, чем отдельные базы данных user_data и user_data_temp?

Comment: Да ничем не хуже. Даже поудобней будет в разных табличках рядом держать. Может заказчик хочет на temp выделить сервер послабее кстати? Сервер послабее и по памяти меньше, чтобы меньше платить. А то, что горячее, закинуть на самый производительный сервер

Comment: @PythonicSpeaker Сайт очень узкой тематики, в день туда будет заходить ну максимум 10 тыс пользователей. Делать архитектуру с максимальным распределением, как у какого нибудь vk или instagram, ну бред же. Любая CMS типа Worpress или DLE в дефолте без проблем пропустит через себя 10тыс посетителей за день, а то и 100 тысяч. Каждый считает своим долгом поучить разработчика, как надо правильно делать.

Comment: Ну поскольку good practice - это всегда указывать не просто имя таблицы, но включая имя схемы/БД, то в принципе пофиг, одна БД на всё или хоть своя БД под каждую отдельную таблицу. А две таблицы user_data и user_data_temp под одну сущность, экземпляры которой отличаются одним-единственным атрибутом approved - так и вовсе дурь несусветная. С другой стороны, кто женщину платит. тот её и танцует... А потому смотрим техзадание. Если заказчик напишет там, что под каждый чих своя схема - так тому и быть. А если нет - так не его собачье дело как. Или дополнение к ТЗ, с соответствующим ростом бюджета.

Comment: Еще об этом [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313867/one-database-or-multiple-databases).

Comment: Ну если так важно для него что "Не будет зависаний", то просто берёте и пользуетесь услугами любой Serverless СУБД, хоть обмасштабируйтесь.